# How to send password to REST service securely?

Tags: python, rest, flask, flask-restful

I am using [Flask-Restful](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to build a REST service. The iOS device will then connect to this REST backend to sync the local data.

The service will be accessed over a **https** connection.

The REST service is stateless and the user has to authenticate upon each request. Hence the username and password will be sent in clear format to the REST service. The backend will hash the password and check against the existing hashed password in the database.

```
api.add_resource(Records, '/rest/records/<string:email>/<string:password>/<string:ios_sync_timestamp>')
```

Now one problem I see with this approach is that the username and password are in clear format as part of the GET url.  The server log will obviously track this. Now if my backend was ever hacked into, the log files would compromise all the usernames and passwords.

What is the best solution to this?  I was thinking maybe sending username and password as POST arguments, but how do I that with GET requests then?

```
class Records(Resource):
    def get(self, email, password, ios_sync_timestamp):
        pass
    def post(self, email, password, ios_sync_timestamp):
        pass
```

Comment: When reading these comments, keep in mind that while you can encrypt a password or API token, you haven't necessarily made things "secure". For example, a developer who incorrectly creates a client for your service that accidentally connects over HTTP versus HTTPS will cause your user's password to be sent over clear text, even though you've set up SSL.

Comment: Thanks, thats true. Since I will be developing the iOS as well, I make sure its done right. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To authenticate each requests with a username and password like you want, you should use: [Basic Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

To use it, it's pretty simple and it works with all HTTP methods (GET, POST, ...). You just need to add an HTTP header into the request:

```
Authorization: Basic <...>
```

The `<...>` part is the `username:password` encoded in base64.

For example, if your login is `foo` and your password is `bar`. The HTTP header should have this line:

```
`Authorization: Basic Zm9vOmJhcg==`
```

Through your **HTTPS** connection, it's secure.

EDIT: Using Flask, you can use [Flask HTTP auth](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flask-httpauth) to achieve this "automatically".

Comment: Thanks, how do I achieve this with `flask-restful` framework?

Comment: In addition, take a look of http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-using-flask-restful - Section named "Authentication"

Comment: Sandro, I studied the whole blog. Very interesting. I have a followup question, if you were so kind to look at it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518042/flask-httpauth-how-is-get-password-decorator-meant-to-work-for-basic-auth

Answer (score 2):

Another solution instead of the Basic Auth in each call as suggested by Sandro Munda is to generate an `API Key` using a `POST` to first check credentials request and then passing it in the request headers. Then you can verify it in each API handler for a strict-grained checking or application-wide using a `@before_request` handler.

### Workflow

- Client sends a `POST` to the server with the credentials (username/pass)
- Server replies with an API Key. Like an hexdigest of something secret.

from now on

- Each time the client needs to send an API request it adds an header (let's call it `X-API-Key` with the API Key.

Comment: This approach sounds interesting too but the second part isn't clear to me. Would you have a small example at hand to illustrate the `passing it in the request headers` back to the client?

Comment: Ahh now I understand it better. So when the server replies with an API Key, that API key is unique to that authenticated user, so that any subsequent access to the REST API that contains that API key in the header can be traced back to him.  In that case I had to save that given API key for that user in database correct? Otherwise how do I know that I had assigned him this API Key in first place?

Comment: @Kave yes. And you can revoke access to that key at any time. This for example might force the app user to re-enter the user/pwd pairs for increased security.