# flask-httpauth: How is get_password decorator meant to work for basic-auth?

Tags: python, flask, flask-httpauth

I wonder if anyone has used this [flask extension](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flask-httpauth) to simplify the http-basic-auth.

Basically I don't understand this [example](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flask-httpauth#basic-authentication-example):

```
users = {
    "john": "hello",
    "susan": "bye"
}

@auth.get_password
def get_pw(username):
    if username in users:
        return users[username]
    return None
```

The `get_password` decorator seems like to return the clear password of the given user and if it matches to the one the user has provided, then the authorization will be granted.

But no one should have access to the clear passwords of the users in first place.  I usually send the clear password and username to the backend, hash the password and compare it to the existing hashed password in the database.

How has this been envisioned?

**UPDATE:**

The link to the docs sheds some more light. since there a second decorator required to achieve this:

```
@auth.hash_password
def hash_pw(username, password):
    get_salt(username)
    return hash(password, salt)
```

Literally the rule is `get_password(username) == hash_password(password)`

The way I understand this to work is `get_password` returns the user's hashed password in the database, which needs to be equal to the currently hashed password defined in `hash_password` method.

The problem is though, I am using [sha256_crypt from passlib](http://pythonhosted.org/passlib/).

```
def verify_password(password, hashed_password_in_db, password_hash_version):
    if password_hash_version == 1:
        return sha256_crypt.verify(password, hashed_password_in_db)
    return False
```

In here you can't hash the given password and compare it to the stored hashed password.  I have to use the method `sha256_crypt.verify(password, hashed_password_in_db)`, which returns false or true.

Is there a way to achieve this or do I have to roll my own custom solution? Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-HTTPAuth/blob/master/docs/index.rst

Comment: Thanks for the link, as it seems to be missing on the projects home. May you please have a look at the updated question? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized this questions remained unanswered.

I am sure the project `flask-httpauth` is great for cases, where you intend to use md5 hash.

But as in my case, if you use `sha256_crypt` you can't make it work with this extension, due the way it works. (See my updated question)

What I ended up doing is to use this [snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/8/) written by the maker of flask.

The method `check_auth` is exactly what I needed as it returns boolean.

In my case I have defined it like this to make it work with `sha256_crypt`

```
def check_auth(email, password):
    em_login_provider = ndb.Key('AuthProvider', get_provider_id(constants.EMAIL, email)).get()        
    if em_login_provider and em_login_provider.active:
        user = em_login_provider.user                
        if user and verify_password(password, user.password_hash, user.password_hash_version):
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm the developer of Flask-HTTPAuth. Sorry I missed this question.

I just released a new version that gives you a way to use your custom function to verify a password. Instead of defining `get_password` and `hash_password` callbacks you can now use a `verify_password` callback that leaves the password verification completely up to you. For example, in your case you would use this callback:

```
@auth.verify_password
def verify_password(email, password):
    return check_auth(email, password)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: When presenting such examples, it helps if you can also show the corresponding HTML form that sends data to the Flask app. When a person who is new to Flask sees your code (even on the Flask-HTTPAuth website), it's hard to understand how control flows toward `verify_password`.