# What's the best way to lock down an internal api on heroku?

Tags: api, security, heroku, flask

I have an internal api hosted on heroku. I need to make sure the only apps that can get get access to it are mine. I want something simple but secure. OAuth seems a bit heavy but I want something I can easily expand to other apps I build. What options do I have?

Answer (score 1):

This is not Heroku related.

You can use common authentication patterns. Such as [the ones explained in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19514538/how-to-send-password-to-rest-service-securely)